# auth_redirect() or wp_redirect() from a specific page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I want to redirect a user to login, when he clicks on a certain menu item of a page. Only that item requires login and then it redirects back to the page. All other pages are open for public viewing.
I searched a lot on how i can use auth_redirect() for a specific page, but to no avail.
Please help.

Comment: create a custom template for that particular page and add `if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {auth_redirect();}` to that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can do the trick.. just take care of condition, i put both, removed the not needed..

```
function my_page_template_redirect()
{

    if( is_page( 'your-page-slug' ) || is_singular('your-post-type' ) /** just removed not need condition if its a page keep page and if its a post keep singular one **/
    {
        if(!is_user_logged_in())
        {
            auth_redirect();
        }

    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect' );
```